# How to write and hide an <h1> tag in jQuery using one line of code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My HTML:

```
<h1 id='heading'></h1>
```

My jQuery:

```
$('#heading').text('Nice Heading');
```

There is supposed to be a way to write it then hide it in one line of code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('#heading').text('Nice Heading').hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this, add in any other attributes you require

```
$('<h1/>', {
    id: 'heading',
    text: 'Nice Heading'
}).appendTo('body').hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('body').append( $('<h1 id=\'heading\'>Nice Heading<\/h1>').hide());
```